# Change to different page while ajax is waiting for reply

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page witch does a couple ajax calls and it ususaly takes about a minute for all of them to complete. Unfortunatly while these calls are not yet replied my browser waits for them to be finished before going to another page. What i want to do is let the ajax calls do there work but stop when a user decided to go to anothere page and let him go instantly. I tried using abort but does not seem to work.

**Code:**

```
    var requests = []

    function getworkLetterList(){
        requests.push(getworkLetterList = $.get("ajax.home.php?get=workLetterList", function(data, status){
            if (status != "success") {
                alert("Fout bij inladen workLetterList");
            }else{
                $("#workLetterList-row").replaceWith(data);
                $("#workLetterList-loader").css("display","none")
            }
        }));
    }
    function getreviewArray(){
        requests.push($.get("ajax.home.php?get=reviewArray", function(data, status){
            if (status != "success") {
                alert("Fout bij inladen reviewArray");
            }else{
                $("#reviewArray-row").replaceWith(data);
                $("#reviewArray-loader").css("display","none")
            }
        }));
    }
    function geteindcijfer(){
        requests.push($.get("ajax.home.php?get=eindcijfer", function(data, status){
            if (status != "success") {
                alert("Fout bij inladen eindcijfer");
            }else{
                $("#eindcijfer-row").html(data);
                $("#eindcijfer-loader").css("display","none")
            }
        }));
    }
    function abortRequests(){
        console.log(requests);
        for (i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) { 
            requests[i].abort();
        }
    }

    $( window ).unload(function() {
        abortRequests()
    });
    $(window).on('beforeunload ',function() {
        abortRequests()
    });


    getworkLetterList();
    getreviewArray();
    geteindcijfer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally sending an ajax request does not cause such delays. However, it may be a client side problem. One possible problem could be the client side processing of the server response or the server needs too much time to process all these requests. Have you checked the response times in the developer tools of [YOUR_BROWSER_OF_CHOICE]?

Comment: Same result as the jQuery one. abortRequests() gets called. there are also no errors in the console.